# Get the cut heights using identify.hclust()

Tags: r, dendrogram, hclust

I am manually cutting a dendrogram created from `hclust` in R using `identify.hclust`. 
The default return of the function is the IDs of observations in each group.
I need this information, but I also need to know the height of this group. Is there any way of doing it? Thanks alot!

Reproducible data:

```
set.seed(1)
dat = rnorm(100,0,1)
hca = hclust(dist(dat))
plot(hca, hang=-1, sub="", xlab="", labels=F)
heightsAndIDs = identify(hca) #Gives only IDs
```

As example, I cut the dendrogram at the following heights by using `identify` and want to get the height of the merge for the branch:

```
segments(3,2,8, col="red")
segments(15,1,18, col="green")
segments(20,1,24,col="blue")
segments(38,1.5,45,col="purple")
segments(75, 1.5, 82,col="cyan")
```

Comment: In addition to `identify()`  try `locator()`

Comment: Thanks, that will help me for sure. Now i need to combine it with the default return

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you could get your answer from the two functions `heights_per_k.dendrogram` and `get_branches_heights` from the R package [dendextend](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/index.html).

Here is a small example:

```
set.seed(1)
dat = rnorm(100,0,1)
hca = hclust(dist(dat))

library(dendextend)
```

For example:

```
> sort(heights_per_k.dendrogram(dend))[1:7]
          100            99            98 
0.00002485728 0.00010400211 0.00020365009 
           97            96            95 
0.00118445439 0.00180321776 0.00215161572 
           94 
0.00230368982 
> sort(heights_per_k.dendrogram(dend), T)[1:7]
        1         2         3         4         5 
4.6163377 4.6162976 3.1585161 1.8779138 1.3384979 
        6         7 
1.1705453 0.9620798
```

Does this give you the tools for getting your answer?